# Pycharm `source` and `source activate` commands

Tags: python, pycharm

In terminal I launch program as follows:

```
1) source env.sh
2) source activate enviroment
3) program --args
```

How can I do the same but in Pycharm and the debug the code?
The third I can do by editing `Script and Script Parameters` in `Run --> Edit Configurations`. But what about first and second items?

Answer (score 1):

The second command seems equivalent to [configure an interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html) in PyCharm.